# Scrolling page/table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So, I have a page which is basically a table.

What I want to do via `html/css/javascript` is auto scroll the page some rows down, stay there for like 30 seconds, do that again if there is more area to scroll down, stay there again for like 30 seconds and do that again and again. If there is no more room to scroll down, go from the top of the page and start scrolling again.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? Here we expect you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please attempt something, then update your question to show a **specific** problem you're having in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ELEMENT.scrollTop` to set the amount of scrolling.
If the height of a row is 64px, lets say, and you want to scroll down 2 rows every 30 seconds, you can do this:

```
var rowHeight = 64;
var wait = 30;
var rowsPerScroll = 2;
var scrollInterval = setInterval(function(){
    window.scrollTop += ((rowHeight * rowsPerScroll)%window.innerHeight)
},wait*1000); //wait * 1000 because wait is in seconds, not milliseconds.
```

If its not working tell me i will edit this post.